# Two way binding angular 8, between child components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8, two-way-binding

I´ve got a problem in Angular 8.
I´m using a angular material stepper, each step is a diferent component an there is a father component that contains all the stepper [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do09L.png)

This is my principal component, as you can see, I´m sending a formgroup named Campaign into three components:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
<mat-step [completed]="false">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>DATOS GENERALES</ng-template>
  <app-step-one [parentFormGroup]="campaign"></app-step-one>
</mat-step>
<mat-step [completed]="false">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>CREAR MENSAJE</ng-template>
  <app-step-two [parentFormGroup]="campaign" [actionsData]="dataCampaign"></app-step-two>
</mat-step>
<mat-step [completed]="false">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>PROGRAMAR</ng-template>
  <app-step-three [parentFormGroup]="campaign" [actionsData]="dataCampaign"></app-step-three>
</mat-step>
<mat-step [completed]="false">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>RESUMEN</ng-template>
  <app-step-four [parentFormGroup]="campaign" ></app-step-four>
</mat-step>
```

How can I pass info form step on, two and three to four??

Comment: You can use `@Output` binding. Plenty of ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

Create a class or interface for communication:

```
export class StepperData {
  step: number;
  data: any;
}
```

Each step component needs an `Output`:

```
@Output()
done = new EventEmitter<StepperData>();
```

When you're ready to go to the next step, send output to the parent:

HTML:

```
<button mat-button matStepperNext (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

TS:

```
next() {
  let stepperData: StepperData = {
    step: <step number>,
    data: <your data>
  }

  this.done.emit(stepperData);
}
```

Get this data on parent and use it on other step components:

HTML:

```
...
<mat-step [completed]="false">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>DATOS GENERALES</ng-template>
  <app-step-one [parentFormGroup]="campaign" (done)="updateData($event)"></app-step-one>
</mat-step>
...
```

TS:

```
updateData(stepperData: StepperData) {
  // you have the stepper component data here
  // update your state and model
}
```

Another way to do it is using a service and observables but using `Input` and `Output` is simpler.

Comment: Thanks but I don´t have a next button, you can go from componente one to three, there is not an ordern in the steppers. I´m going to try to pass the data from componente 1, 2 and 3 to the father and then father pass data to the component 4.

Comment: I´ve found this property: selectionChange, so I can see everything on my form any time that change the stepper, but how can I pass that info everytime that I change the stepper??

Comment: You need to be aware of when user is done with an step so that you can trigger the `done` event. `selectionChange` happens outside of `mat-step` so it's not useful in this scenario.